# Deployment issues on Tomcat

Tags: deployment, tomcat, grails

I am unable to deploy grails war in tomcat .

1. Copied all 55 jars to `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib/grails-jars/`
2. Added `shared.loader= ${catalina.home}/shared/lib/grails-jars/*.jar`

And started tomcat successfully. Now deployed grails war in deploy folder (war is ~572.4KB).

The console shows these errors :

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
28 Jan, 2010 11:35:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2010-01-28 11:36:06,294 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
```

My application contains 4 plugins :

1. hibernate-1.1.2
2. liferay-exploded-0.8
3. portlets-0.7
4. portlets-liferay-0.1

Could any one please help me .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this might be a Hibernate version problem, [as described here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4547).

Comment: Hi kaleb,

Yeah, the same issue i was facing .

I had hibernate-1.1.2 plugin. This plugin generated automatically at the time of project creation .
Do we need to install higher version plugin ?

Comment: Hi kaleb, my bad. Please ignore previous comment.

Yes you are right, the issue is with hibernate jar in Liferay tomcat.I replaced with latest jar and works well.

Thanks a lot Kaleb, your answer saved me a lot of time. 

thanks,
srinath a